# search overlay on full screen size (not opening)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

hey all i want to create overlay full screen search on click so i tried this:

this is the navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-color">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid -->
```

and this is overlay code:

```
<div id="search">
<button type="button" class="close">×</button>
<form>
    <input type="search" value="" placeholder="SEARCH KEYWORD(s)"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

and this is the css:

```
 #search {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
#search input[type="search"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: -51px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  outline: none;
}
#search .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 61px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  background-color: limegreen;
  border: black;
}
#search .close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: limegreen;
  border-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-size: 27px;
}
#search.open {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and for jquery i used this:

```
  $(function() {
  $('a[href="#search"]').on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#search").addClass("open");
    $('#search > form > input[type="search"]').focus();
  });

  $("#search, #search button.close").on("click keyup", function(event) {
    if (
      event.target == this ||
      event.target.className == "close" ||
      event.keyCode == 27
    ) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
  });

  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

i know it is a lot of code but i really need help, on click is not working and on inspect element, nothing is showing on console as error....

any help would be appreciated

thank you for your time guys

Comment: https://codepen.io/svenhakvoort/pen/GYEjxe, it seems to work fine here. Is this the behavior you expect?

Comment: Is there more jQeury? Maybe something else is preventing the click event from firing